# Java Ubuntu PATH for compile/run

Tags: java

Ubuntu noob here. When using Windows I just copy paste this in cmd:

```
set Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
set HomePath= C:\Program Files\Java\ jdk1.8.0_60
```

What would the syntax for this be in Ubuntu? assuming `/usr/bin/java`. A concise answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer said, the linux equivalent is this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

But how will you find out the `/path/to/your/jdk`? (Assuming you are a noob here). For that, you will have to run this command:

```
which java
```

`which` is a standard linux command that gives you the full path to any file (or blank if the file isn't locatable). This will return you a path like `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_05/bin`, and after removing the `/bin` at the end, you can take the rest of path and assign it to `JAVA_HOME`.

Hope that helps.